# Does the Inverse ralation object is the same with the original?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have been using Laravel for months, and the [`inverse ralation`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) bothers me.

Considering the following example.

There are two Eloquent models, and the relation is defined as below

```
class Customer extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order:class);
    }
}


class Order extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer:class);
    }
}


$customer1 = Customer::select()
    //->where('id', '=', 1)
    ->with('orders')
    ->first();

$customer2 = $customer1->orders[0]->customer;

if ($customer1 === $customer2) {
    echo 'Same'. PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'Not the same'. PHP_EOL;
}
```

`$customer1` and `$customer2` should be the same. But they are not.
What I want is that `$customer1` and `$customer2` be the same, just like [`Yii2 does`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#inverse-relations)

> With the word **same**, I mean they should be the same instance instead of two instances with the same customer data.

Did I miss something? Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Looks like there is no way "tell" `$orders` that your customer has been pulled, you don't need to pull it from the database again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has no *active record* implementation. There is no master who keeps track of what objects have been fetched from the database. Each object tracks its own changes, but has no knowledge of other objects that exist in memory.

Answer (score 0):

From your relation, you can see every customer can have multiple order and order must have a customer. So in your $customer1 variable, you have an eloquent model object and in $customer2 you have an id. How could you compare them?? Try to compare between ID. Laravel doesn't work that way you are expecting.

```
  $customer1 = Customer::select()
        //->where('id', '=', 1)
        ->with('orders')
        ->first();

    $customer2 = $customer->orders[0]->customer;

    if ($customer1->id === $customer2) {
        echo 'Same'. PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo 'Not the same'. PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Comment: `$customer1` and `$customer2` contain exactly the same data right? So they should be the same instance.

Comment: No, they are not same $customer1 is an eloquent object and $customer2 is normal id

Comment: Why `$customer2` is a normal id? Could you explain?

Comment: $customer1->orders[0]->customer here you are accessing an object then an array then a normal column which is actually the value of that column, and you are accessing from $customer1. So $customer2 is just a value form $customer1 object

Comment: The is `One to Many Relation`. Each customer has many orders. So `$customer1->orders` would be an array of orders. Meanwhile, `$customer1->orders[0]` would be and order eloquent instance and `$customer1->orders[0]->customer` would be an customer.

Comment: yes it's a customer id but not an eloquent object so they are not same, think out of the box

Comment: You might try and see what it is. :)